# Interpreting Interaction with two Continuous Variables

Tags: interaction, poisson-regression

I am estimating two count models (Poisson regression).  The second count model is a robustness check on my dependent variable.  I slightly adjusted how I measured my dependent variable.  Here are my results

```
                    Model 1    Model 2
EXP x Divided Govt  -2.073    -2.898
                    (1.181)   (1.182)
EXP                 17.672    -14.756
                    (20.538)  (21.223)
Divided Govt        0.014       0.013
                    (0.014)    (0.014)
```

Here are the predicted counts for the minimum and maximum values for teach of the interaction components.

Model 1:

```
      Min Divided Govt   Max Divided Govt
Min Exp         1.88               4.26
Max Exp         6.23               2.18
```

Model 2:

```
         Min Divided Govt  Max Divided Govt
Min Exp       2.37              5.31
Max Exp       7.02              1.15
```

My confusion is that the predicted counts move in the same direction for both models.  However, the sign for the EXP variable is different for model 1 and 2 (and all the other interaction variables have the same signs).  Why is that?

Also, in your opinion, what is the best way to substantively display your results from an interaction with two continuous variables?